# Sequelize.INTEGER vs DataTypes.INTEGER

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

In [code from 2016 using sequelize ORM](http://lorenstewart.me/2016/10/03/sequelize-crud-101/), I see model types defined with this pattern:

```
 module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
     const Tasks = sequelize.define("Tasks", {  id: {
       type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
       [ ...etc.]
```

However in the current sequelize docs you see [most prominently documented](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html): `Sequelize.INTEGER` (or other type then integer).
At the same time in the current docs I find also `DataTypes` still `documented/used`: [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/variable/index.html#static-variable-DataTypes).

On same page the `Sequelize.INTEGER` is used..., is that only for deferrables or something?

I tried to find whether this altered over time or something but could not find it.

When `Sequelize.INTEGER` is 'current solution' could I just alter above code into:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {
  const Tasks = sequelize.define("Tasks", {  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    [ ...etc.]
```

Or would using `Sequelize` as argument somehow make this fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter in both of them is just the `sequelize` package itself You can use any of them which is on you what you want to use

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
```

You'll notice in your index.js of models (if you set up as suggested) that you do something like the below, where you are passing in `sequelize` as the second argument.

```
const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize);
```

This exposes the data types. It doesn't matter what you call it. For example I am calling it `abc` in below code you can use any name

```
module.exports = (sequelize, abc) => {
  const Driver = sequelize.define('Driver', {
  firstName: {
       type: abc.STRING(),
       allowNull: false
  },
  last_name: {
       type: abc.TEXT,
       allowNull: true
  },
  email: {
      type: abc.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
  },
  password: {
      type: abc.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
  }
```

Same with migrations.